# Error when making SSL connection from Java client to .NET server

Tags: java, .net, ssl, x509certificate, self-signed

I am in the process of learning SSL and in this process I am attempting to create an SSL connection between a .NET server with a Java client. I use a self signed certificate for this purpose. I don't want to use the standard keystore in Java so I create a custom keystore and load that instead.

I use the following steps to generate the certificate and the pfx file to use at the .NET server end.

1. Generated a cerficiate using the following command on windows.

   > makecert -r -pe -sr "localhost" -$ individual -n "CN=localhost" -sv
   >   .pvk -r localhost.cer
2. Converted this to a .pfx so that I can load this certificate on the .NET server app.
3. Exported the .cer file as a .pem (Base64 format).
4. Took the .cer file (the public component of the above mentioned certificate) and created a .jks file (JavaKeyStore) to use as the java client using the following command.

   > keytool \
   >         -import \
   >         -v \
   >         -trustcacerts \
   >         -alias 0 \
   >         -file <(openssl x509 -in localhost.pem) \
   >         -keystore mystore.jks\
   >         -storetype JKS\
   >         -storepass ez24get
5. Loaded this .jks in the Java client app and initiated the connection with the following code

   > ```
   > FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("res/myjksstore.jks");
   > KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
   > trusted.load(fis, "ez24get".toCharArray());           
   >
   > TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
   > trustManagerFactory.init(trusted);
   >
   > SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
   > context.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
   >
   > Socket socket = context.getSocketFactory().createSocket("localhost", 443);
   >
   > String str = "abc123";
   >
   > socket.getOutputStream().write(GeneralUtil.toByta(str.length()));
   > socket.getOutputStream().write(str.getBytes());
   >
   > socket.setKeepAlive(true);
   > ```

But when I try to write data to the socket, I get the following error at the server end

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

My server code looks as follows...

> X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate("localhost.pfx", "abc123");
>
> TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 443);
>   listener.Start();
>
> while (true) {
>
> try     {       TcpClient tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
>
> ```
>   NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
>
>   SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(networkStream);
>
>   sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(cert, false, SslProtocols.Default,
> ```
>
> false);
>
> ```
>   byte[] data1 = new byte[4];
>
>   sslStream.Read(data1, 0, data1.Length);
>
>   int len = BitConverter.ToInt32(data1, 0);
>
>   String message = "Length of incoming data " +
> ```
>
> BitConverter.ToInt32(data1, 0);
>
> ```
>   byte[] data2 = new byte[len];
>
>   sslStream.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);
>
>   message += "   Message: " + ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data2);
>
>   Thread.Sleep(1000);
> ```
>
> }   catch (Exception ex)
>   {
>   } 
>   }

The exception occurs at the line

> sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(cert, false, SslProtocols.Default, false);

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to connect to your server with openssl and check avaliable ciphersuites. `openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -CAfile <path to cert.pem>` Post please output of this command.

Comment: Did you successfully connect using the standard keystore with some variant of this code, or is this your first shot at the SSL connect?

Comment: Nope.. I didn't pursue this much further because I had to let go of SSL Streams due to performance related reasons. I just implemented an RSA handshake to share a session key and then used AES encryption to handle the transport. Similar to what SSL does.

Answer (score -1):

SSLEngine (obtained from SSLContext) must be set to client mode (setUseClientMode)

Comment: That's the default, and he isn't using the `SSLEngine` at all. -1